# Google Maps Api v2 не отображается на телефоне

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api

Пишу приложение в Android studio. Карты отображаются и работают на виртуалке а когда создаю релизовый apk и устонавливаю на телефон то карты не отображаются только бежевого цвета прямоугольник. Помогите пожалуйста разобратся, проблема в Google Api key? я вроде сделал все как подсказывала Android studio при создании Google maps Activity.

Comment: Для релизного apk нужен релизный ключ. Вы меняли ключ?

Comment: то есть я должен сделать два ключа, с одним дебажить, а с другим генерить apk для устройства? и если я вдруг с ключем для релиза задебажу он у меня испоганится и надо будет делать новый?

Comment: Суть в том, что дебажный ключ годится только тогда когда вы делаете отладку на устройстве.(когда запускаете напрямую из ide) Кстати если вы создаете apk, то дебажный ключ уже не годится. Нужно делать релизный и использовать его. Ключ для релиза не испоганится, но если вы поменяете key store то и релизный ключ нужно будет переделать.